# Can an old MacBook be upgraded to OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, mac

I've just got a really old MacBook and I want to upgrade it to the latest OS version. I do not know if it supports to be upgraded, the config of this MacBook is as below:

```
Model Name: MacBook
Model Identifier: MacBook1, 1
Processor Name: Intel Core Duo
Processor speed: 1.83 GHz
The number of processors: 1
Total Number Of Cores: 2
L2 cache: 2 MB
Memory: 1 GB
Bus speed: 667 MHz
Boot ROM Version: MB11.006
```

If I increase the memory, can I upgrade it?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't.

OS X Lion, the latest OS X release, only supports 64-bit CPUs. The `MacBook1,1` version has a Core Duo processor with a 32-bit architecture, therefore you won't ever get to upgrade it to Lion.

Adding memory will definitely help boost performance a little, but I wouldn't expect too much, since the CPU itself isn't that fast either. Note that this model can only take a maximum of 2 GB RAM.

If you want to check whether your MacBook supports upgrades, check Wikipedia's [list of model specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macbook#Model_specifications). It even has a column for the maximum OS version supported.

Comment: Haha: I have an old Dell with almost the same internals, and I have it running the Windows 8 consumer preview just fine. Take that Apple ;)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - What does this have to do with the answer or the topic at hand?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Without wanting to start a flame war, if you ever want to leave 32-bit behind, then at some point you have to stop supporting it. The difference between the tightly coupled Apple ecosystem and the PC/Windows world is so huge that I don't even think it's worth comparing these.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Backwards compatibility and keeping to existing conventions has always been the strength of Microsoft, while Apple more readily discarded old technology and conventions to move forward (or what they consider forward) with greater ease. Both clearly have their own advantages and disadvantages. Completely unrelated, if you really want to annoy someone, create a file or folder named `CON` on their Windows system's desktop and watch them try to get rid of it.